# Showing a modal dialog message and awaiting user answer from blazor code behind

Tags: modal-dialog, user-input, blazor

I followed [this guide](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/creating-a-reusable-javascript-free-blazor-modal) for my `Blazor` app to show modal dialogs. I know about [Blazored.Modal](https://github.com/Blazored/Modal) which was not used here for learning purposes.

The point here is that I'd like to use this for some sort of user validation and execute code only when user says to. I use a `ModalService` to show a prompt within another `MyBackgroundService` doing some stuff that require the user choices at some point.

Here's the main page's code:

```
@page "/"

@inject ModalService _modalService
@inject MyBackgroundService _myService

<div>
    <button @onclick="onShowClick" class="btn btn-primary">Show</button>
    <button @onclick="onRunClick" class="btn btn-primary">Run</button>
</div>

@code {
    protected async Task onShowClick() {
        // shows MyControl in a modal form => working just great!
        _modalService.Show(typeof(MyControl));
    }

    protected async Task onRunClick() {
        await _myService.Run();
    }
}
```

Here the code of the `ModalService` class:

```
public class ModalService {

    public event Action<Type> OnShow;       
    public event Action OnClose;

    public void Show(Type contentType) {
        if (contentType.BaseType != typeof(ComponentBase)) {
            throw new ArgumentException($"{contentType.FullName} must be a Blazor Component");
        }
        OnShow?.Invoke(contentType);
    }

    public void Close() {
        OnClose?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Here the sample code of `MyBackgroundService` class:

```
public class MyBackgroundService {
    private readonly ModalService _modalService;

    public CalSyncerService(ModalService modalService) {
        _modalService = modalService;
    }

    public async Task Run() {
        var processResult1 = await firstLongProcess();
        string userAnswer = "Ok";
        if (processResult1 != true) {
            // something went wrong so far => it might be risky to continue => ask user if Ok...
            // of course, we're not awaiting the user answer here, this is what I need to correct!!
            _modalService.Show(typeof(MyControl)); 
        }
        if (userAnswer == "Ok") {
            await secondProcess();
        }
    }
}
```

What would be A CLEAN way to wait for the user answer? Using an action, or maybe even better, an `async` method, showing the modal dialog and waiting for the dialog to close to return the answer?

Answer (score 0):

So my CLEAN way of doing it involves a Component with a layout engine, it does other things too, like show a "working" modal, wrapped in using so it doesn't get left.

First off the Razor Component:

```
@inherits LayoutEngineBase

@if (Spinning)
{
    <div id="workingModal">
        <h1>@Message</h1>
    </div>
}

@if (NeedsConfirmation)
{
    <div id="confirmModal">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h3>@ConfirmationMessage</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-success" @onclick="ConfirmYes">Ok</button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="ConfirmNo">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

@ChildContent
```

Then its Base:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Web.Shared
{
 
    public class LayoutEngineBase : ComponentBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This is used for the contained Razor markup.
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter]
        public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// This fires when something has changed, useful with Cascaded Pages
        /// </summary>
        [Parameter]
        public EventCallback OnStateChanged { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Bind this to whatever needs to change when working is in progress
        /// </summary>
        public bool Spinning { get; internal set; } = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Bind this to whatever needs to change when a confirmation is required
        /// </summary>
        public bool NeedsConfirmation { get; internal set; } = false;        
        
        /// <summary>
        /// MarkupString will render raw HTML to Razor.
        /// </summary>
        public MarkupString Message { get; internal set; }

        protected MarkupString ConfirmationMessage { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this internally to for a re-render StateHasChanged()
        /// </summary>
        internal async virtual void RaiseChange()
        {
            await OnStateChanged.InvokeAsync();
        }


        private CancellationTokenSource FinishConfirm;
        private  bool DialogResponse;

        private string _stationName;

        public string StationName
        {
            get => _stationName;
            set
            {
                _stationName = value;
                RaiseChange();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Wrap this in a using to switch spinning state on and off at bracket boundaries
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">Used to set the display message during working.</param>
        /// <returns>New IDisposable Worker</returns>
        public Worker Working(string message = null) => new Worker(this, message ?? "Working");

        /// <summary>
        /// Await this to wait for a user response.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message"></param>
        /// <returns>True for Ok, False for Cancel</returns>
        public async Task<bool> ShowConfirmAsync(string message)
        {
            ConfirmationMessage = new(message);

            NeedsConfirmation = true;
            try
            {
                using (FinishConfirm = new())
                {
                    await Task.Delay(-1, FinishConfirm.Token);
                }
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { } // we want to cancel it.

            return DialogResponse;
        }

        protected void ConfirmYes()
        {
            ConfirmDialog(true);
        }

        protected void ConfirmNo()
        {
            ConfirmDialog(false);
        }

        private void ConfirmDialog(bool confirmation)
        {
            DialogResponse = confirmation;
            if (FinishConfirm.Token.CanBeCanceled)
            {
                FinishConfirm.Cancel();
            }
            NeedsConfirmation = false;
            RaiseChange();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// When created this will start the spinning, when disposed it will stop it. Not really needed by external code, but need to be public for accessibility level.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed class Worker : IDisposable
    {
        private LayoutEngineBase _parent;

        public Worker(LayoutEngineBase parent, string message)
        {
            _parent = parent;
            _parent.Message = new MarkupString($"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{message}&hellip;");
            _parent.Spinning = true;
            _parent.RaiseChange();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _parent.Spinning = false;
            _parent.RaiseChange();
        }
    }
}
```

You can then wrap your MainLayout.razor with it:

```
<LayoutEngine @ref="layoutEngine" OnStateChanged="LayoutEngineStateChanged">
    <div class="main grid">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            ...Navigation...
        </div>
        <div class="content p-4">
            <CascadingValue Value=layoutEngine>
                @Body
            </CascadingValue>
        </div>
    </div>
</LayoutEngine>
```

Notice I've @ref the layoutEngine and also cascaded it.

The code for MainLayout:

```
@code
{
    protected LayoutEngineBase layoutEngine = new();    

    protected void LayoutEngineStateChanged()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected async void LogOut()
    {
        var confirm = await layoutEngine.ShowConfirmAsync("Are you sure?");

        if (confirm)
        {
            await AuthenticationStateProvider.LogOutUserAsync();
            StateHasChanged();

            NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the LayoutEngine Component has an OnStateChanged which you can then use to tell the MainLayout that the StateHasChanged();

What should interest you here is the LogOut function, here the var confirm await ShowConfirm, which only ends the task when someone clicks Ok or Cancel.

Also, the "Working" option can be used with the following code, as long as you accept the cascaded parameter layoutEngine:

```
using (layoutEngine.Working("Doing Stuff"))
{
    Do Stuff...
}
```

This shows a modal with "Doing Stuff" written across it until the using ends.

This obviously requires a bit of CSS, which I'm not going to post here, that's different for everyone.